# FeynRules and defineing lagrangian

Tags: packages, physics, feyncalc

We are going to add new term to Standard Model, I defined a new vector field

```
V[5] == {
  ClassName -> zp,
  SelfConjugate -> True,
  Mass -> {mzp, Internal},
  Width -> 0,
  Unphysical -> False,
  PropagatorLabel -> "zp",
  PropagatorType -> Sine,
  PropagatorArrow -> None,(*or maybe forward*)

  ParticleName -> "zp",
  FullName -> "Z', Z prime particle"
  }
```

and two new parameters (mass and coupling constant)

```
gZpNeu == {
  ParameterType -> External,
  Value -> 1,
  ComplexParameter -> False,
  ParameterName -> GZPNEU,
  Description -> "Coupling Constant of Z' abd Neutrinos",
  BlockName -> NEWCOUP,
      OrderBlock -> 1, 
  InteractionOrder -> {NP,1}
  },
mzp == {
  ParameterType -> External,
  Value -> 0.01,
  ComplexParameter -> False,
  ParameterName -> MZP,
  Description -> "Z' Mass", 
  BlockName -> NEWCOUP,
  OrderBlock -> 2
  }
```

I added them to SM.fr file; 
our Lagrangian is:

```
 Lours := Block[{la},
        la =-0.25 (del[zp, mu] - del[zp, nu]) (del[zp, mu] - 
            del[zp, nu]) + 0.5 mzp*mzp (zp[mu])*(zp[mu]) + 
            gZpNeu zp[mu] vebar.Ga[mu].ve;
        la + HC[la]];
LBSM := LSM + Lours ;
```

everything works fine, FeynmanRules[LBSM] give the vertices. but when I try to produce FeynArts output I see this warning 
[image]

and in I face some issues in FeynArts,I guess the problem is with the Lagrangian, since when I remove our term everything works fine.  I did some simple example about BSM before  and use the results in FeynArts but in this case I can't figure the problem out.
I'll be more than grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: You should contact the creator directly about this question.  You can find the relevant contact information on the first page of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.1921v2.pdf) paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the problem,
The warning is just a warning, not an error new term added to Lagrangian.
But...
if one add some new particle to Standard Model, when you see this warning that means FeynRules Create new list of particle or even new parameter, when he/she creates output for FeynArts so it is essential to take a look at created file (new  particle in .mod) or (new parameter .pars)to become aware of them, you CAN NOT use the list of particle that exists before in FeynRules in SM.fr.